# how to reset bokeh figure using python callback

Tags: python, bokeh, reset

i have generated 3 bokeh plots using bokeh server. we have reset tool in-built. but the requirement is to reset whole figures in a single button click.Rest should be like , reset zoom level , pan ,selection etc..

Answer (score 0):

Just put all the plots in a grid. For vertical lineup use `ncols = 1`, for horizontal `ncols = 3`

```
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot

grid = gridplot([plot1, plot2, plot3], ncols = 1)
show(grid)
```